# I want to fire Modelpopup extender on click event of a button which is inside Sharepoint Gridview

Tags: model, sharepoint-2010, modalpopupextender, spgridview

I have one dynamically created SPGridview.
In one column of the grid i have link button.
I want to show modelpopup extender on click event of this link button.

Any answer with sample code are most welcome

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get what you wanted from [this](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/confirm_gridview_deletes_with.html) article.

I would suggest you to use SPDialog Framework that is used in 2010 Version of SharePoint.
These two links Should Help you . [Andrew Article](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2009/12/08/sharepoint-2010-dev-tidbit-ndash-want-to-create-your-own.aspx) & [Islams's](http://ishaalan.wordpress.com/2010/05/24/using-the-sharepoint-2010-dialog/)

But one more thing you will need to use a Seperate Page for the Popup.